# How to write Javascript code in Cordova JS file?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-3, visual-studio-2015

This is practically the first day I step into Cordova in Visual Studio 2015. I have no problem in any sort of coding in C# and MVC but Cordova seems like a total new thing, because I couldn't find anywhere I can write JS code in JS file

In one of my view file, I have one JS file that is auto generated and has the code below

```
'use strict';
app.homeView = kendo.observable({
onShow: function() {},
afterShow: function() {}
});

// START_CUSTOM_CODE_homeView
// Add custom code here. For more information about custom code, see http://docs.telerik.com/platform/screenbuilder/troubleshooting/how-to-keep-custom-code-changes

(function () {
app.homeView.set('title', 'Home');
})();
// END_CUSTOM_CODE_homeView
```

In this file, I tried many different ways to write my button click event but none of them is working. There is no error in the console. Just no respond.

I wrote the code within the CUSTOM_CODE part, as well as inside the (function () {  })();, just nothing work.

Please guide me on the proper of writing JS code in the JS file.

And please let me know if there is any issue in using jQuery in Cordova compare to normal web development

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have shown is the latest ES6, which has improved significantly from the previous ES5.

```
app.homeView = kendo.observable({
onShow: function() {},
afterShow: function() {}
});
```

The snippet above provided by you is how objects are declared.

As most of the browsers are still using ES5, The current solution is to write in ES6 syntax and transpiled into ES5 syntax. Some of the tools that allows you to do that are babel and typescript.

you may wanna visit the following websites to learn more about the syntax.

[Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial)

[Babel playground](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/)